# Why does `whoami` give a different answer than Current User in Users & Groups?

Tags: macos, user-account

I don't recall exactly what info I was asked to provide at the time I set the mac up, which is leading to some confusion.

On my mac, when I run `whoami` in a terminal, it tells me `aerovistae`, my general username. However, if I open Users & Groups, it tells me the current user is `myFirstName myLastName`.

Why is this? Is it the same account, and it has two different name properties? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same account. The name displayed in Users & Groups is your full name, the one shown by `whomami` is the name of the account as known to the underlying Unix system (and also used as the folder name for your home folder). To check yourself, open Users & Groups, unlock if necessary and then right-click on your user name in the left column. This will show you the technical details behind your account.

[image]